# open a new view controller programmatically gives me a black screen

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have checked similar questions but none of them worked for my case (they all mention a function loadView which I do not have). I think it is quite easy what I want to do but I cannot figure out why it is happening.

I want when pressing a button in a cell to open a new view controller programmatically. Here is my code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    dealViewController=[[DealViewController alloc]init];
    if (indexPath.row==0){
        [self presentModalViewController:(UIViewController *)dealViewController animated:TRUE];
    }

}
```

and in my other controller:

```
@implementation DealViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    NSLog(@"Opened");
}
```

the `Opened` is printed but the simulator shows a black screen. I have also tried this:

```
dealViewController=[[DealViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"DealViewController" bundle: nil];
```

but I get a segfault. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try to change the background color and see if something changed?

Comment: Are u using storyboard?

Comment: it seems it is loading your vc. whats the problem?

Comment: @CRDave Yes I am using storyboard. I changed the color but yet again black.

Comment: @Pfitz I cannot see the content. I see only a black screen.

Comment: If you're using a Storyboard then you need to either load the VC programatically from the storyboard (i.e. not initWithNib) or use a segue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

[Apple Doc for StoryBoard](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStoryboard_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Also, you can do it via performSegue:withIdentifier.

[A Good Tutorial on same](http://www.appcoda.com/storyboards-ios-tutorial-pass-data-between-view-controller-with-segue/)

```
   - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"<Your StoryBoard_Name" bundle:nil];

    dealViewController=[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController_Identifiter"];
        if (indexPath.row==0){
            [self presentModalViewController:(UIViewController *)dealViewController animated:TRUE];
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following code if you are using storyboard

```
   - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"dealViewController" bundle:nil];

    dealViewController=[[DealViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"DealViewController" bundle: nil];
        if (indexPath.row==0){
            [self presentModalViewController:(UIViewController *)dealViewController animated:TRUE];
        }

    }
```